# Django - circular import module and submodule

Tags: python, django

I am reading many doc, blog, and SE questions about this topic but I cant get it right. I have a circular import between my models.py and tms.py in a same module named maps

models.py

```
from maps.tms import tileMapConfig

class LayerMapOptions(models.Model):
    layer = models.ForeignKey(Shapefile)
    basqui_map = models.ForeignKey(BasquiMap)
    position = models.IntegerField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    visible = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    styles = models.ManyToManyField(LayerStyle, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LayerMapOptions, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.basqui_map.date_updated = datetime.now()
        self.basqui_map.save()
        tileMapConfig(self.basqui_map.pk)
```

tms.py:

```
from maps.models import LayerMapOptions

result = LayerMapOptions.objects.filter(basqui_map__pk=map_id)

def tileMapConfig(map_id):
    ...
```

This result in the following error:

> ```
> from maps.models import LayerMapOptions ImportError: cannot import name LayerMapOptions
> ```

What would be the way to import those submodules without conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put your import into the function that uses it:

```
def tileMapConfig(map_id):
    from maps.models import LayerMapOptions
    ...
```

Or

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):        
    from maps.tms import tileMapConfig
    ...
```

Modules are only imported once, so each time it re-enters the function, it will not reimport the whole module, it will only fetch it from the already imported modules, so there is (almost) no performance issue.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the full namespace.

```
import maps.tms
maps.tmstileMapConfig(self.basqui_map.pk)
```

The other issue is that you have some global code running during the import:

```
result = LayerMapOptions.objects.filter(basqui_map__pk=map_id)
```

When importing a module, the code in the module gets executed, so if you can move this line into a function or method, that will delay the execution of that line until after both modules have fully imported.

Here's a better explanation:

http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm